# String IndexOf within a sentance of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to perform a simple indexOf on my array
the thing is that it just looks for the entire text within my array node

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("hello world");
var result = arr.indexOf("hello");
```

my problem is that the result I get is -1
is there any way to get the indexOf to search within each of the array element without another loop?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, its not possible to use arr.indexOf to search for substring, you have to use loop.

Although you can add method to array to call it to find the substring in array.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BEsvj/4/)**

*Function definition.*

```
arr.containsIndexOf = function(str) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if(arr[i].indexOf(str) != -1)
         return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

*Function call*

```
arr.containsIndexOf("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Adil said you need to use a loop.

```
var myArr= new Array();
myArr.push("hello world");
function searchArr(txt, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            return i
        }
    }
}
```

use this function like this

```
searchArr("hello",myArr); //returns 0
```

You might have a array with multiple "hello", so you need to know where all of them are.

```
myArr.push("hello world")
myArr.push("hello Pluto");
myArr.push("hi sun");
myArr.push("Hello Moon");
function searchArr(txt, arr) {
var arrList = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
           arrList.push(i);
        }
    }
return arrList
}
searchArr("hello",myArr); //returns [0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: You may like to return -1 in your first function (the simpler one) in case the search item was not found in the array.

Answer (score 1):

As @Adil said, No you can't use `indexOf` function of `Array` to find substring but you can use `indexOf` of `String` to find substring:

**Example:**

```
var mystr = 'hello world';
var index = mystr.indexOf('hello');
```

With your example you should try somethings like:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("hello world");
var mystr = arr[0]; // this is String object
var index = mystr.indexOf("hello");
```

**Documentation:**
[string.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
[array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("hello world");
var result = arr[0].indexOf("hello");
```

Because this is an Array so you need to access it with it's index.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the whole of the string `hello world` into one index of the array so `indexOf` will only work when you use as it needs to match the whole item in that array index.

`var result = arr.indexOf("hello world");`

One way to do it would be like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("hello world");

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if(arr[i].indexOf('hello') != -1)
         return i;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpBp4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get index of the first matching item in an array
// or -1 if the item is not found
function SearchArray(arr, txt) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf(txt) > -1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Function call:

```
var someArray = new Array();
someArray.push("hello world");

SearchArray(someArray, "hello");
```